# Error: iterator should return strings, not collections.OrderedDict (did you open the file in text mode?)

Tags: python, csv

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd

counter = dict()

with open('train.csv', 'r') as csv_file: 
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

# skip headers
next(csv_reader)

for row in csv.reader(csv_reader):

    pixels = row[:-1] # without label
    pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype='uint8')
    pixels = pixels.reshape((28, 28))
    image = Image.fromarray(pixels)

    label = row[-1]

    if label not in counter:
        counter[label] = 0
    counter[label] += 1

    filename = '{}{}.jpg'.format(label, counter[label])
    image.save(filename)

    print('saved:', filename)
```

I have this piece of code and as the title of the post says, I'm not able to read the CSV file due to that error. I've tried all read mode possible. Any idea? I'm a mac user and I'm using python 2.7 in case that helps. Thank you.

Comment: `for row in csv_reader:` - no need to read it again

Comment: Also, the entire block should be in the `with` statement to guarantee you process the file before it is closed.

Comment: Also, you might get an error here: `label = row[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already read the file once here:

```
with open('train.csv', 'r') as csv_file: 
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

You can directly use it, **no need** to call `csv.reader(...)` again:

```
for row in csv.reader(csv_reader):
```

Change it to:

```
for row in csv_reader:
```

Comment: `reader` doesn't actually read the file; it's a *wrapper* around the file object that will read from the file as someone reads from the wrapper.

Comment: It's true... what a mistake. Thank you.